# Software Update fails

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Trying to install OS Yosemite and get this:

> Can't connect to the Apple Software Update server.

Already tried to delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist` - did not help. What shall I do?

[image]

Comment: You'll just have to **wait** a few more hours :-)

Comment: The same was discussed here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6579420?start=0&tstart=0 Any variants?

Comment: It's hard to say right now, with thousands of people hammering Apple servers trying to download Yosemite. So it might be just an overloaded server farm or it may be something else. Might be worth to wait a few days (or follow the ideas from the forum).

Comment: I saw this error two days ago, so I little worry about safety...

Comment: Then it's probably not related to Yosemite, but nevertheless debugging might be difficult right now.

Comment: I try to wait and hope that I do not have to reinstall the current system because of virus or something else. By the way, thanks for your answers!